# Hide Adsense on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adsense

I have a site built in Ruby On Rails which has many ads in different templates and views. It is hard to actualy remove each ad between tests and deployments.

I don't know whether Google approves many impressions (even if without clicks) on localhost.

How do you deal with this issue?

Maybe it is a good solution to set a variable/constant available everywere to enable/disable ads easily.
Do you think it is a good solution? If so, how do I declare a global variable for views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure displaying ads locally is fine as long as you don't click them. I've displayed ads locally on a few projects and I have yet to be shut down by the man.

I don't have the exact same issue, I have ads enabled/disabled for different types of accounts - I just put the ad code in a partial.

You could create a partial like this:

```
<% unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development" %>

ad code here.

<% end %>
```

If you're doing this in more than one place I'd create a helper method:

```
def display_ads?
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != "development"
end
```

Then your partial code would become this:

```
<% if display_ads? %>

ad code here.

<% end %>
```

Comment: you could go one step further with that helper and use a block
def display_ads
  if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != "development"
    yield
  end
end

and in the partial:
<% display_ads do %>
  <div> Buy Pepsi </div>
<% end %>

Answer (score 9):

One thing you can do is go to the [Allowed Sites](https://www.google.com/adsense/publisher-whitelist-view) settings at AdSense (it’s in the AdSense Setup > Allowed Sites tab) and check the “only allow certain sites to show ads for my account” option, and then add all the domains where AdSense is allowed to appear, *without* including `localhost` or any other development, staging or non-production domains, obviously.

> If you put your ad code on a page not on this list, **ads will still show, but impressions and clicks will not be recorded**.

That way you can have ads in your development environment without worrying about accidentally clicking on your ads, and without skewing your AdSense stats.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 

The question was based on the Google TOS and although a RoR application specific answer is provided above I don't think it really answers the spirit of the question.